# Debian/Ubuntu:How to compile a Linux kernel on one machine and use on other machines (same architecture)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, kernel, linux-kernel

Debian/Ubuntu: How to compile a Linux kernel on one machine and use on other machines (same architecture)?

I know how to do it on the same machine. But to use a compiled kernel other machines, is tricky for me.

For example,

I have done `make`

But how about `sudo make modules_install install` ?
This will install things to my current machine.

What is good practice to compile a kernel on a fast machine but use it on other slow/(or fast too) machines.

Otherwise I have to compile, install it every time, which is time consuming.

Note:

On Ubuntu webpage, there are ways to do similar thing. But it is only good for Ubuntu kernels. Not for upstream kernels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since they're Debian machines, use `make deb-pkg` (instead of `make`, `make install`, etc.), which is part of the upstream kernel sources. That will generate a few Debian packages; you can scp those around and install with `dpkg -i`.

Comment: You also have `make-kpkg` on Debian, which is supposed to be deprecated but is still nicer than `make deb-pkg` I guess.